# Changing data to be visualized in jvector Map

Tags: jvectormap

I have two types of maps of Nepal (districts map of Nepal and ecological map of Nepal). I have two data sets for each of the above type. I am trying to create a visualization where users can first choose what type of map  they want and then later what data they want to be visualized. (using dropdowns).

These are the codes for dropdowns.

```
    <select id="changeMap">
      <option>Change Map</option>         
      <option value="ecoMap">Ecological Region</option>
      <option value="world_mill_en">Districts</option>
    </select>

    <select id="changedata">
      <option>Change Data</option>
      <option value="Caste 1">CASTE 1</option>
      <option value="Caste 2">CASTE 2</option>
    </select>
```

This is the jvector Map function.

```
            <div id="container"></div>

            <script>
            var vmap = '<div id="vmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>';
            $('#changeMap').on('change', function () {
                var _map = $(this).val();
                $('#vmap').remove();
                $('#container').append(vmap);
                $('#vmap').vectorMap({
                    map: _map,
                    backgroundColor: '#000000',
                    enableZoom: true,
                    regionsSelectable : false,
                    series: {
                    regions: [{
                    values: data,
                    scale: ['#fffad6', '#d05300'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                }]
                  }});
            });
            </script>
```

Now, how do I make this drop- drop down combination work to visualize?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess u want a complete dynamic implementation of the map. I used the same for creating Australia's map with dynamic regions plotted on it on the fly.

Initially create the jvectormap object with path attribute left empty as shown below:

```
var auJSON = {
"insets": [
    {
        "width": 900.0,
        "top": 0,
        "height": 850.8001894248416,
        "bbox": [
            {
                "y": 1125139.6460741498,
                "x": 12575140.762771795
            },
            {
                "y": 5412845.645305354,
                "x": 17110794.900221862
            }],
        "left": 0
    }
 ],
  "paths": {
  },
  "height": 850.8001894248416,
  "projection":
    {
        "type": "merc",
        "centralMeridian": 0.0
    },
  "width": 900.0
};
```

Now, on click on any of the option you have to insert the objects in the path attribute dynamically and finally render the map. I created an array of objects below.

```
        d3.select("#regionSVG").selectAll("path")
            .each(function () {
                var obj = {
                    "path": $(this).attr("d"),
                    "name": $(this).attr("name"),
                    "id": this.id
                }
                that.regionPathArray.push(obj);
            });
```

Now i passed on this array to fill in the empty path attribute as below.

```
initRegionLoading(that.regionPathArray);

function initRegionLoading(arr) {
    var initialJSON = auJSON;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            initialJSON.paths[arr[i].name] = arr[i];
    }
    $.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'au_reg_en', initialJSON);
}
```

And then i displayed the map.

```
        this.ausie_map = new jvm.WorldMap({
            map: 'au_reg_en',
            container: $('#auMap_' + that.zoomLevel),
        });
```

That solves my problem. Hope it does yours too.